# How to get the "touched" state of oculus controller button?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I checked the document and **OVRInput.cs** of Oculus Integration. So I can get the status when pressing the button on controller by using "Get()", "GetDown()" and "GetUp()".

```
Debug.Log(OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.RawButton.B));
```

However, I noticed that when you touch but do not press the button, the controller still can check this status and change the animation of the virtual hand.

How could I detect this status of the button?